# Cross domain SignalR Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, cors

I have a working .NET website with authentication up and running (Identity 2.0 via Owin & https://identityazuretable.codeplex.com/)

I would like to use websockets primarily for the SignalR transport, but because the domain is running on cloudflare (the free plan does not currently support websockets) I cannot use SignalR on the same domain and get websockets. So to work around this issue I have a subdomain websockets.example.com, which does not use cloudflare, but does point to the same application.

However, I now wish to authenticate the SignalR connections based on their forms authentication token in a cookie. However the cookie does not get sent when I do the below, or when SignalR connects to websockets.example.com

JQuery Request:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "//websockets.example.com/signalr/hubs",
   type: "POST",
   xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true
   }
});
```

Or:

```
$.connection.hub.url = '//websockets.example.com/signalr/';
$.connection.hub.start({ withCredentials: true });
```

Headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Cookie:ARRAffinity=805c328533b85a33c6fdeb4870bd41f00e05fd898b5d784f2635656f9525466b
Host:websockets.example.com
Origin:http://example.com
Referer:http://example.com/Page
```

Response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://example.com
```

EDIT: Owin Config:

```
app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(new CorsOptions
                {
                    PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
                    {
                        PolicyResolver = context =>
                        {
                            var corsPolicy = new CorsPolicy
                            {
                                AllowAnyHeader = true,
                                AllowAnyMethod = true,
                                SupportsCredentials = true,
                                AllowAnyOrigin = false,

                            };

                            corsPolicy.Origins.Add("http://example.com");
                            corsPolicy.Origins.Add("http://www.example.com");
                            corsPolicy.Origins.Add("http://websockets.example.com");
                            corsPolicy.Origins.Add("https://websockets.example.com");
                            corsPolicy.Origins.Add("https://example.com");
                            corsPolicy.Origins.Add("https://www.example.com");
                            return Task.FromResult(corsPolicy);
                        }
                    }
                });
                map.RunSignalR();
            });
```

Comment: try to add to response:
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *

Comment: @MajoB I had not thought about that, but my Owin config should be doing it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is with the way your authentication cookie is set. This would explain why the cookie isn't sent to websockets.example.com via SignalR or a normal CORS request made via `jQuery.ajax`.

To ensure cookies set by a parent domain are sent to submdomains you need to explicitly define the domain with the Set-Cookie header:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=.mydomain.com
```

If you don't explicitly define the domain, cookies will only be sent back to the *exact* domain that set them.

http://erik.io/blog/2014/03/04/definitive-guide-to-cookie-domains/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/719967

Comment: Sounds good - I actually ended up implementing a work around using SignalRs caller state (as the page that loads signalR loads from the domain where authentication works).